# How does the `Object#define_singleton_method(symbol, method)` works in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, singleton-methods

From the [`Doc of define_singleton_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method)

I got two syntax to define the `singleton` method as below :

> **define_singleton_method(symbol) { block } -> proc** :

With the above syntax I tried the below code and the syntax I understood:

```
define_singleton_method :foo do |params = {}|
 params
end
#=> #<Proc:0x20e6b48@(irb):1 (lambda)>

foo
#=> {}

foo(bar: :baz)
#=> {:bar=>:baz}

foo(bar: :baz ,rar: :gaz )
#=> {:bar=>:baz, :rar=>:gaz}
```

But need someone's help to figure out one example of each with the below syntax.

> **define_singleton_method(symbol, method) -> new_method**

as per the doc - The method parameter can be a *`Proc`*, a *`Method`* or an *`UnboundMethod`* object. I didn't get any examples there.

Can anyone help me here to get one example of against the ***italic*** words?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `Proc` object is created by using `lambda`, `proc`, `->`, `Proc.new` or the `&` syntax in a parameter list. A `Method` object can be obtained by using the `method` method and an `UnboundMethod` can be obtained by using the `instance_method` method. So here are examples of each of these:

```
p = Proc.new {|x| puts x}
m = method(:puts)
um = Object.instance_method(:puts)

define_singleton_method(:my_puts1, p)
define_singleton_method(:my_puts2, m)
define_singleton_method(:my_puts3, um)

my_puts1 42
my_puts2 42
my_puts3 42
```

Answer (score 5):

With a `Proc`:

```
define_singleton_method(:foo, proc{ 'foo' })
foo #=> 'foo'
```

With a `Method`:

```
oof = 'oof'
oof.define_singleton_method(:foo, oof.method(:reverse))
oof.foo #=> "foo"
```

With an `UnboundMethod`:

```
oof = 'oof'
oof.define_singleton_method(:foo, String.instance_method(:reverse))
oof.foo #=> "foo"
```

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for the examples for giving me. :)

Comment: Is it the body `oof.method(:reverse)` of the singleton_method of `:foo` ?